# "Limanuel"? Help me out this is here any word in Greek for "God with us"?

Tags: greek, bible-versions, rabbinic-interpretation

Emmanuel "God with us" (Isaiah 7:14)
What is the Greek word for "God with us"? I believe it is Emmanuel. However, somebody strongly argued that it is Limanuel which I didn't fine in the Bible nor in Greek leterature.

Comment: https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=H6005&t=KJV

Answer (score 3):

The LXX transliterates the Hebrew עִמָּנוּ אֵל in Isaiah 7:14 into Greek as Εμμανουηλ, but in Isaiah 8:8, it translates it as μεθ᾽ ἡμῶν ὁ θεός (“God [is] with us”).

The Greek word Εμμανουηλ would be transliterated into English as “Emmanuel.”